# Oracle - DECODE - How will it sort when not every case is specified?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to use `DECODE` to implement custom sort:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl ORDER BY DECODE(col1, 'a', 3, 'b', 2, 'c', 1) DESC
```

What will happen if col1 has more values that the three specified in decode clause?

Comment: then you should add another parameter as a default: `decode( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )`. Anyway, this kind of sort would work anyway ( c is before b if sorted DESC )

Comment: Have you actually tried just running it to see what happens?

Comment: @Najzero How is c be before b is DESC sort?

Comment: @kyooryu  well, oracle can sort strings fine too (ASC or DESC): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#i1005980

Comment: @Najzero Oh, I thought you meant it would come first in the query I presented above.

Comment: well, you could write `ORDER BY col1 DESC` ... then rows with value 'C' in col1 would come before those rows with value 'B'. But of course rows with value 'Z' would come above 'C' and so on, if you want to force C,B,A to be sorted on top and everything else to be below, you could use `DECODE(col1, 'a', 3, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 0)` ( that would result in values not beeing a,b or c getting decoded to 0 and by DESC-sorted after all a/b/c values )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DECODE will return NULL, for the values of col1 which are not specified.
The NULL-Values will be placed at the front per default .

if you want to change this behavior you can either define the default value in DECODE

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl ORDER BY DECODE(col1, 'a', 3, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 0) DESC
```

or NULLS LAST  in the order clause

```
 SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl ORDER BY DECODE(col1, 'a', 3, 'b', 2, 'c', 1) DESC NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 1):

the decode function will return NULL value and it is at the bottom of your sort. You can verify it: 
select decode('z','a', 3, 'b', 2, 'c', 1) from dual;

you can also control the appearance of the null value with NULLS LAST/NULLS FIRST in the order clause.

Comment: By default, NULLs appear first for DESC order by clause. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2171079

Answer (score 1):

Normal it expects some result as a default if not NULL is all you get so add some value at the end like this

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl ORDER BY DECODE(col1, 'a', 3, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 0) DESC
```

That way if col1 has more values they all will return 0